# Is there any way to save and load a complex data structure to binary file in C#?

Tags: c#, file, serialization, binary, deserialization

## The problem

I am writing a program in C# which is use for save and load a list of object in specific structure like this:

```
SIGNATURE\r\n
SIZE\r\n
OBJECT_DATA\r\n
SIZE\r\n
OBJECT_DATA\r\n
\r\n
```

`Signature` is a primitive string that contain a private key to separate my data file with others file.

`SIZE` is an integer value present the number of bytes that `OBJECT_DATA` use.

`OBJECT_DATA` is a class that contain my data.

## What I've tried

I've found many solution in Stackoverflow and almost all of them use `BinaryFormatter` which is insecure and should not be use.

I also took a look at [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-net/) but I still confused to apply it for my problem.

## My Idea

I think the serialize and deserialize stage for the solution will look like this:

Serialize (assume that the input/output file is a binary file):

```
1. Open output file and write the signature.
2. Loop over the source object list
    - With each item, calculate the size of item and write it to output file.
    - Write object data to binary file. (I'm still confusing in this step)
    - Write "\r\n" to mark this is the end of the item.
```

Deserialize

```
1. Open input file and read the Signature
2. If the Signature fit with my secret key:
    - Loop until end of file
        - Read the SIZE value.
        - Read object and create instance of it's class.
```

## Update

The `OBJECT_DATA` I mentioned is an instance of a class:

```
public abstract class IShape
{
    public State Configuration { get; set; }
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; } = [];
    public abstract UIElement Draw();
    public abstract IShape Clone();
    public BitmapImage Preview { get; set; }
}
```

The structure of `State Configuration`:

```
public class State
{
    public DoubleCollection StrokeDashArray { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Stroke { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Fill { get; set; }
    public double StrokeThickness { get; set; }
}
```

I think Protobuf-net is a good way to serialize an object to `Stream` but my class contains some value from `System.Windows.Media` and I'm not sure if I can serialize it with using Protobuf-net.

Comment: Protobuf-net is a good alternative due to its efficiency and widespread use.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're looking for - you present a potential file format at the start of the question... is that actually a requirement that you're trying to fulfil, or just one option? (Mixing binary and text data is a pretty fragile approach, IMO.)

Comment: @JonSkeet meh, the format shown actually reminds me of "RESP" (the redis protocol) - pretty reliable (and it isn't a million miles from HTTP)

Comment: If the data format is fixed, you basically just need to sit down and write the bytes using your own scratch buffers, and either the `Stream` or `Pipe` APIs (typically `Stream`, but `Pipe` has some advantages for advanced scenarios) - is the format of `OBJECT_DATA` already known, or is that something you're still unsure of? because: serializing an arbitrary type is not a trivial task

Comment: The file format is just one option. My original problem is finding a way to store and load a list of object with a custom-defined binary format.

Comment: @Queensalats you mention you looked at protobuf-net; I'm the author - is there anything you got stuck on? serializing an object that has a collection/list of some other object: is pretty trivial with that; trust me: you *do not* want to do this yourself from first principles unless you absolutely have to

Comment: You have apparently found protobuf-net. What problems do you have? I find the examples on the linked page to be quite clear. The details of the protocol are a bit complicated, but you do not really need an in depth understanding of the protocol if you just want to store and load some data.

Comment: @MarcGravell the format of `OBJECT_DATA` is already known, but it contains some values from `System.Windows` (such as `UIElement`, `SolidColorBrush`, `Point`, ...), so I don't know how to serialize it. Is it possible for me to convert all of them to string values for easy saving, and whenever I load it, can I just convert them back to `System.Windows`?

Comment: @Queensalats that's where things get complicated; tools like protobuf-net can help with simple POCO/DTO types - that's their niche; when it comes to custom 3rd party models, it is very hard to comment - the API is very individual - and for all I know could involve OS handles. It *is* possible to write a custom serializer for such scenarios that integrated with protobuf-net, but it isn't trivial and requires knowledge of both the serializer and the specific custom thing being serialized. Happy to discuss individual scenarios, but probably too large for a Stack Overflow comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my own problem by combining `IShape` and `State` into a POCO class.

```
public class ShapeProtocol
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StartX { get; set; }
    public string StartY { get; set; }
    public string EndX { get; set; }
    public string EndY { get; set; }
    public string StrokeThickness { get; set; }
    public string Stroke { get; set; }
    public string? StrokeDashArray { get; set; }
    public string? Fill { get; set; }

    public ShapeProtocol() { }

    public ShapeProtocol(IShape shape)
    { /* Constructor */ }

    public static IShape ConvertBack(ShapeProtocol protocol)
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

Then I implement a `ShapeSerializer`:

```
public static class ShapeSerializer
{
    public static string Serialize(IShape shape)
    {
        var shapeProtocol = new ShapeProtocol(shape);

        var properties = from p in shapeProtocol.GetType().GetProperties()
                         where p.GetValue(shapeProtocol, null) != null
                         select p.Name + "=" + p.GetValue(shapeProtocol, null);

        // this string will be the OBJECT_DATA I mentioned. 
        // the result will look like this: Name=Ellipse;StartX=240;StartY=48.2;EndX=411.3;EndY=140;StrokeThickness=1;Stroke=#FFDC143C
        return String.Join(";", properties.ToArray());
    }

    public static IShape Deserialize(string rawData)
    {
        var _raw = rawData.Split(';').ToDictionary(p => p.Split("=")[0], p => p.Split("=")[1]);
        var deserialized = new ShapeProtocol();

        var _properties = typeof(ShapeProtocol).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in _properties)
        {
            try
            {
                var value = _raw[property.Name];
                property.SetValue(deserialized, value, null);
            }
            catch { /* assume that value is null */ }
        }

        return ShapeProtocol.ConvertBack(deserialized);
    }
}
```

The workflow will like this:
[image: Workflow of Serialize/Deserialize]

Then I just use `FileStream` to store/load the data with the file structure in the very fist of this problem.

Expressing my gratitude to @JonSkeet and @MarcGravell. Both of you have been a great source of inspiration in addressing this issue.